# How can a function return its argument list as an array reference

Tags: perl

How would I go about writing a function that returns its arguments as a reference to a array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sub f {
   return [@_];
}

$ref = f(2, 3, 5);
print "@$ref\n";
```

The `[@foo]` construct creates a reference to a new, anonymous array (copy of `@foo`), while the `\@foo` construct creates a reference to the `@foo` array, whose contents might later change.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to create a subroutine that returns its arguments as an array:

```
sub array {[@_]}  # returns an array reference that is a copy of its argument

sub array_verbose {  # the same as array(), but spelled out
    my @copy = @_;
    return \@copy;
}

sub capture {\@_}  # returns a reference to the actual argument array
```

There are several important differences between `array` and `capture`:

```
my ($x, $y) = (3, 4);

my $array = array $x, $y;
my $capture = capture $x, $y;

say "@$array, @$capture";  # prints '3 4, 3 4'

$x++;

say "@$array, @$capture";  # prints '3 4, 4 4'

$$capture[1] *= 2;

say "@$array, @$capture";  # prints '3 4, 4 8'

say "$x $y";  # prints '4 8'
```

As these examples show, the array produced by `array()` is copied by value, and those values are independent from the original arguments.  The array produced by `capture()` retains a bi-directional alias to its argument list.

Another difference is in speed.  `capture()` is about 40% faster than `array()` since it does not have to copy the elements of the array (or even look at them for that matter).  This speed difference will of course vary depending on the length of the argument list.

An additional effect of `capture()` not even touching its elements is that if an argument that would normally allocate memory is used, that allocation will not happen until the argument is touched:

```
my %hash;
my $hashcap = capture $hash{a}, $hash{b}, $hash{c};

say join ', ' => keys %hash; # prints nothing

$_++ for @$hashcap;

say join ', ' => keys %hash; # prints 'c, a, b'
```

In my own code, I usually spell `capture()` as `cap()` or just write it inline:

```
my $y = sub{\@_}->(map $_**2, 1..10);
```